# Help with figuring out asus motherboard capacitor values

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

I have dented capacitor on my mobo which creates short...
I need to replace it but i am having tough time figuring out which one it is.

First Line : FP

2nd Line : 22Dx

3rd Line : 10 1

4th line : 16

Thanks for help.

By line i mean looking from top that is what is written on top of it.

[image]

Comment: A picture would be better.

Comment: What the hell is line? What is this referring to?
You can get a rough idea of the value from the size, and be conservative with the voltage rating. The question is whether there was a cascade failure which caused something else to fail or if it was just that. You can also desolder another capacitor that looks the same and measure its capacitance.

Comment: That dent isn't nice but it doesn't seem as if it would cause  a short. How do you know it's shorting? Did you measure the voltage across it?

Comment: A picture with the markings on the part actually legible would be even better. Put the cell phone down and borrow a real camera.

Answer (score 2):

I'd hazard a guess that it's a 16V, 22uF capacitor.  You can get some sense of confirmation by comparing its dimensions to other manufacturers' 16V 22uF caps.  This [Panasonic](http://www.panasonic.com/industrial/components/pdf/ABA0000CE114.pdf) part is 4 or 5 mm dia (depending on ESR) and 5.8mm tall. Measure your damaged part and see if it's a comparable size (electrolytic capacitor volume is roughly proportional to it's rated voltage * capacitance).

Without being able to identify an exact match, you'll want to pay up for low ESR, high ripple current, and possibly extended temp.